# taking the log of every element in a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, logarithm

How can you take the log base 10 of every element in a sparse matrix (COO)?

```
>>print type(X)
<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import math
X.data = math.log(X.data,10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.log10` rather than `math.log10`:

```
import numpy as np
X.data = np.log10(X.data)
```